# Python 'eventual'/asynchronous assertions

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have a python feature spec that is testing an asynchronous process that is entirely separate from my step definitions (i.e. the process doing the work is not managed by the test case).

My step looks like this:

```
@then("the document is inserted")
def step_impl(context):
    with context.pg_client.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql.SQL('select jdoc from collection1 where id=%s'), (context.expected_insert_id,))
        json_string = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

The problem is the thing that will make the test pass will take a few seconds to happen between the previous step and this one.

So is there any builtin helper that will try to execute the step multiple times over a timeout?

What i'm really looking for is the python equivalent (if any) to scalatest's [eventually](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.8/org/scalatest/concurrent/Eventually.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written some code to do this:

```
def eventually(f, step_time_seconds, max_trys=10, current_try=0):
    try:
        f()
    except Exception as e:
        if current_try < max_trys:
            time.sleep(step_time_seconds)
            eventually(f, max_trys, step_time_seconds, current_try + 1)
        else:
            raise e
```

This seems suspiciously like something that should be a standard assertion though!